# Defining getters and setters after the object is instantiated

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, getter

This bit of code comes from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters):

```js
var o = {
  a: 7,
  get b() { 
    return this.a + 1;
  },
  set c(x) {
    this.a = x / 2
  }
};
$('body').append(o.a + '<br>')
$('body').append(o.b + '<br>')
o.c = 50;
$('body').append(o.a + '<br>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What I would like to do is break it down even further. I've gotten as far as line 3 like so:

```
var o = {}
o.a = 7
o.get b() { // broken
```

Is there a way that I can break the getters and setters out so that it's not one long definition inside the `o = {}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
Object.defineProperty(o, "b", {
  get: function() {
    // return something
  }
})
```

See demo below:

```js
var o = {};
o.a = 1;
Object.defineProperty(o, "b", {
  get: function() {
    return this.a + 1;
  }
});
console.log(o.b)
```

Answer (score 3):

[Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) is what you're looking for:

```
var o = {};
Object.defineProperty(o, 'a', {
  get: function() { return 1; },
  set: function(val) { console.log(val) }
});
```